# Повторить анимацию n раз в течении n времени

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сервер на nodejs, который отправляет на фронт js массив данных с координатами точек на холсте. Данные приходят каждые 500мс и я хочу плавно анимировать перемещение точек на холсте
Никак не могу придумать тактику. Помогите :(

Comment: Во-первых, нет гарантии в правильном порядке получения данных. Во-вторых, задержка в получении отдельной позиции точек может быть слишком большой чтобы ее ждать. Исходя из этого, нужно определить допустимую задержку в "актуальности" данных, размечать каждую порцию порядковым номером, накапливать несколько порций прежде чем отрисовывать. В случае задержки очередной порции больше нормы, пропускать шаг. Дельту положения точек (расстояние) поделить на количество кадров за шаг (500мс/16.6 => 30 дискретных кадров за один шаг) и перемещать точки на каждом кадре на эту часть расстояния (1/30).

Comment: Учитывая, что известно следующее положение точек (если это допускается), то можно строить кривую Безье, смягчая переходы. Но над этим надо подумать хорошенько. Или тупо формировать ломаную. Это не сложно. В случае пропуска порции данных, брать двойной временной отрезок и соединять его, выделяя в 2 раза больше времени. Вроде не сложно все, берите эту тактику, не пожалеете.

Comment: @Leonid , большое спасибо за идею. Буду пытаться это реализовать
Накапливать данные на 2-3 хода вперед конечно надежно, но есть еще другие анимации, завязаны на синхронность. Отставание в 2 секунды уже будет некрасиво (все таки для себя делаю) :)